Issues with Panels not displaying in basic Swing application
I wanted to add a panel to this basic swing application however it is affecting the program from displaying properly. Could I get help as to why?
package welcome.netbeans;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class WelcomeNetbeans extends JPanel {
    private static final float LABEL_FONT_SIZE = 60.0f;
    private static final int PADDING = 60;
    private static final String TITLE = "Wecome To My GUI!";
    private static final Color BACKGROUND = new Color(51, 255, 189);
    
    private final JLabel label;
    private final JPanel panel;

    WelcomeNetbeans() {
        panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBackground(BACKGROUND);
        panel.setVisible(true);
        
        label = new JLabel(TITLE, SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, LABEL_FONT_SIZE));
        Border border = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(PADDING, PADDING, PADDING, PADDING);
        label.setBorder(border);
        label.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame window = new JFrame();
                window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                window.add(new WelcomeNetbeans()); 
                window.pack();
                window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                window.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    
}

window
I have tried setting the label to be visible thinking that was affecting it from showing up, which did not work for me. I am new to Java, so any commentaries or suggestions would be great. Swing seems very finicky for me.
Thanks!

Your code is schizoid. You say extends JPanel but you don't. You should run with that, in which case, this is the ctor you need:
    public WelcomeNetbeans() {
        setBackground(BACKGROUND);
        label = new JLabel(TITLE, SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, LABEL_FONT_SIZE));
        Border border = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(PADDING, PADDING, PADDING, PADDING);
        label.setBorder(border);
        label.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

Result:


Your code is schizoid. --- Is this part of the answer? I mean, does it really help in any way anyone? Quote from the help center: There’s always a real human being on the other end of that network connection, however misguided they may appear to be.

Yes it is the answer. See definition 2 here I'm willing to edit this though

Oh, ok, thanks for clarifying, I was only aware of definition 1 for this word (and as a result misjudged it as toxic attitude). Maybe something like there are discrepancies in your code, or anything similar would not create such a first impression to someone who used to know that only definition 1 exists for this word (like me). But that's just my fault of not knowing the language very well.
